# Registros repetidos dentro de una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla Vendedor(Id, ClienteId, local_Id)
Necesito consultar los ID de Vendedor que tengan un mismo clienteId para dos Local_Id especificados. 
Usando Sql server 2014

Habia hecho algo como esto pero no estaria funcionando:

```
select id from Vendedor
where local_id in (1233, 7581)
group by cliente_id
having count(cliente_id)>1
```

Comment: Entiendo que debiera ser `select cliente_id` y no `select id`

Comment: Me queda la duda ¿Solo quieres identificar los vendedores con datos repetidos o vas a hacer algo más con ellos? Me huele a un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy)

Comment: O más bien `group by id`

Comment: Si hago select cliente_id me quedo con los id de clientes repetidos. Pero necesito los ID de vendedores los cuales tienen ID de clientes repetidos en los locales dados.

Comment: @EnzoSambucetti te invito ha que leas: [sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794/107347) especificamente las secciones _¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?_ y _Ejemplo de datos_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay necesidad de volver a consultar, solo basta con agrupar correctamente, en tu caso, como requieres saber quienes estan en mas de un local por vendedor, tienes que agrupar por vendedor y cliente.

Te recomendaría poner en tu búsqueda la condición del vendedor, porque como explicaste el local se pudiera repetir por vendedor.

Te anexo un ejemplo de cómo dejarías tu consulta:

```
declare @vendedor as table /*declarando tabla temporal de vendedor*/
(
    Id Int,
    Local_Id Int,
    ClienteId Int
)

insert into @vendedor  /*insertando valores*/
values
(1,1,1),
(1,2,1),
(1,3,1),
(1,4,2),
(1,4,3),
(2,5,1),
(2,6,1),
(2,7,1),
(3,8,2),
(4,9,3)

/*Consulta agrupada por IdVendedor y ClienteId*/
    select Id as IdVendedor, ClienteId, count(ClienteId) as VecesRepetido from @vendedor as Vend
    where Local_Id in (1,2)
    group by Id,ClienteId

/*Resultado*/
IdVendedor  ClienteId   VecesRepetido
     1          1            2
```

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo hay 2 locales distintos, puede ser más eficiente repetir un poco el código.

```
SELECT id 
FROM Vendedor v
WHERE local_id = 1233
AND EXISTS( SELECT * 
            FROM Vendedor v2
            WHERE v2.local_id = 7581
            AND v2.cliente_id = v.cliente_id);
```